# Do "running down the street" and "run down the street" have the same meaning?

Tags: gerunds, reduced-relative-clauses, gerund-clauses

> I suddenly found myself running down the street.
>   l suddenly found myself who run down the street.

Is *running down the street* a gerund clause or reduced relative clause?

Comment: A gerund is a noun formed from a verb, but "running" here is a present participle. The second sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: Although I edited your question for clarity, what you ask in the title isn't the same thing that you ask in the body. So, it's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Before trying to label the grammar, your sentences need to be grammatical....